# Diffusion equation with nonhomogeneous boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following problem:

Use the method of separation of variables to solve the equation 
$$w_t=w_{xx}$$
BC: $w_x(\pi,t)-w_x(-\pi,t)=0$ and $w(\pi,t)-w(-\pi,t)=2\pi$

IC: $w(x,0)=0$.

This is what I have done so far:

Take $c(x,t)$ such that $c(\pi,t)-c(-\pi,t)=2\pi ,c_x(\pi,t)-c_x(-\pi,t)=0$

Take $v = w-c$, then $v(\pi,t)-v(-\pi,t)=0 ,v_x(\pi,t)-v_x(-\pi,t)=0$

Seek solution of $v(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$

BCs become: $X(\pi) = X (-\pi), X_x(\pi) = X_x (-\pi),$

At the end, I have $v(x,t) = x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n cos{(nx)}e^{-n^2t}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n sin{(nx)}e^{-n^2t}$.

I know that afterwards I would have to do Fourier series, but I am not clearly sure how.

If someone can help me with this or tell me where I do wrong, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: $A_n,B_n$ must be such that $v(x,0)=0$, so you are left to get the Fourier series of $-x$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. There is a standard formula for the coefficients in terms of an integral, which you can compute using integration by parts.

Comment: @Ian hi Ian, how can we be left with the Fourier series of $-x$? Sorry, I'm a bit confused as how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $v(x,t)=x$ is a solution of the heat equation with $v_{x}(\pi,t)-v_{x}(-\pi,t)=0$ and $v(\pi,t)-v(-\pi,t)=2\pi$. This allows you to reduce to a new problem where $u(x,t)=w(x,t)-v(x,t)$ is a solution of the heat equation satisfying
$$
           u_{x}(\pi,t)-u_{x}(-\pi,t)=0,\\
           u(\pi,t)-u(-\pi,t)=0,\\
               u(x,0) = w(x,0)-v(x,0) = -x.
$$
The separated solutions of this problem have the form
$$
                  c_n e^{inx}e^{-n^2t}, \;\;\; n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots
$$
The problem involving $u$ has the solution
$$
                  u(x,t)=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}ye^{-iny}dy\right)e^{inx}e^{-n^2t}.
$$
Then $w(x,t)=v(x,t)+u(x,t)$ is the desired solution:
$$
             w(x,t) = x-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}ye^{-iny}dy\right)e^{inx}e^{-n^2t}.
$$